# Grouping users for document access in Office 365's Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I'm used to SharePoint 2010, and the version bundled with Office 365 is giving me some navigation problems. We want to define three groups of users: Group A, Group B and Admins who will be able to access and view all the documents in a document library tagged with an "audience" metadata tag for Group A, Group B or either (respectively). Is this level of control doable in the bundled version of SharePoint? I didn't see anything in the user setup to define which group a user belongs to, nor can I find anything in the library settings.

Comment: How about using item level permissions?

Comment: @uberz91 that's Plan B...but looking for an easy way to do it. Or at least being able to assign item level permissions to a GROUP rather than to a bunch of individual users.